# What does %xP mean in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I came across this line of code and I'm having a tough time figuring out what %xP is doing.

```
result = "0x%xP"%address
```

Isn't `%address` a modulus or is this performing some kind of formatting?

Comment: String formatting https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 5):

It's a format string.  It's a literal `0x` followed by the `address` as a hexidecimal number (`%x`) followed by a literal `P`.

Some examples:

```
>>> '0x%xP' % 1
'0x1P'
>>> '0x%xP' % 10
'0xaP'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that is exactly what I was thinking but the capital P was throwing me off.